# How to fix method invocation 'setIcon' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: java

How to fix

> method invocation `setIcon` may produce `java.lang.NullPointerException`?

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]); 
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
}
```

I'm getting this message when setting icons to a tab layout.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: In this example this probably means the `tabLayout` variable is null at the moment. Please provide more of your code to show where it should initialize.

Comment: @SimonBaars It that variable were `null`, then his IDE would complain about `getTabAt`, not `setIcon`.

Comment: @SimonBaars That could be null, but `getTabAt(n)` can also return null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should fix your warning:

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
    if (tabLayout!=null){
      if (tabLayout.getTabAt(0)!=null)
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
      if (tabLayout.getTabAt(1)!=null)
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]); 
      if (tabLayout.getTabAt(2)!=null)
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this resolves it, it's not a clean solution. I'm assuming this is Android TabLayout. `getTabCount` is available, so you could just check the number of tabs once.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that `tabLayout` is not null

```
if(tabLayout == null){
    return;
}
```

And also check that whatever `getTabAt` returns is not null

```
ActionBar.Tab x = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
if(x != null){
    x.setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
}
```

BTW, you probably have some misconfiguration on your IDE since this is usually a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that getTabAt(x) returns is not null:

```
private void setupTabIcons(TabLayout tabs) {
    int tabIcons[] = {R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon2, R.drawable.icon3};
    TabLayout.Tab tab;

    for (int x=0; x<3; x++) {
        tab = tabs.getTabAt(x);
        if(tab != null){
            tab.setIcon(tabIcons[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your `setIcon` method called before the `tabLayout` is setup with `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`, this will throw a null pointer exception in runtime.

To fix the run time error, you should call `setupTabIcons()` after your `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);` line in `onCreate` method of the activity.

But this still shows the warning in android studio, so to remove the warning and also prevent run time error, you should change your code to get tab index instead of setting it manually such as 0,1,2 as in your `.getTabAt(0)`, `.getTabAt(1)`, `.getTabAt(2)` parts

For the clearance, I will put an example from my code:

```
private TabAdapter tabAdapter;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_action_profile,
        R.drawable.ic_action_people,
        R.drawable.ic_action_messages
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the two
    // primary sections of the activity.
    tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    tabAdapter.addFragment(new AccountFragment(), "Account");
    tabAdapter.addFragment(new HomeFragment(), "People");
    tabAdapter.addFragment(new CommunicateFragment(), "Messages");

    viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    for (int i=0; i<tabLayout.getTabCount();i++) {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabIcons[i]);
    }
}
```

Note: Please make sure to have equal amount of icons in `tabIcons` array as you are creating tabs.